# iPhone keyboard in UIWebView does not go away

Tags: iphone, html, dom, uiwebview

I have an UIWebView that loads a HTML form.

When I select a text field the keyboard appears.

When I type and hit "Go" the form is submitted and the next page loads, but the keyboard does not go away, it stays on the screen.

The only way to get rid of the keyboard is to press the 'done' button on the keyboard or press the HTML submit button in the form.

Is it possible to make the keyboard disappear after hitting the Go button?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to have the active input resign the focus as the form submits.  The easiest way would be to call `.blur()` on all your inputs in your form's `onsubmit` event handler

```
<form onsubmit="document.getElementById('myInput').blur();">
    <input type="text" id="myInput"/>
</form>
```

Comment: what if you have no control over the HTML in the webview?