# UIWebView won't hide keyboard

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need to hide the keyboard as soon as a page starts loading. I've tried all commonly suggested approaches discussed e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563201/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-on-a-uiwebview)

Following approaches have no effect on the keyboard

```
[webView endEditing:YES];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.activeElement.blur();"];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.blur();"];
```

I invoke them in `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `UIViewController`'s returned `YES` here for `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`.

```
- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal {
  return NO;
}
```

Have a look at that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762251/how-to-hide-the-ipad-keyboard-from-a-modal-view-controller).

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your answer. i write this methods

```
- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal {
  return NO;
}
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [webView endEditing:YES];
}
```

works for me

Answer (score 0):

try

```
webView.delegate = self;
```

and inside the `-webViewDidFinishLoad:` delegate method

```
[webView resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: @Erik try  your approaches inside delegate methods:

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)awebView

OR

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView
instead of you tried earlier